# How to document an Apps Script Library to refer to a default service type?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing a library with my utilities functions, one of them is this:

```js
/**
 * Open spreadsheet by passing its link instead of its key
 * @return {Spreadsheet} the spreadsheet object
 * @param {string} link the link to the spreadsheet
 */
function openByLink(link) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById(link.match(/key=([^&]*)/)[1]);
}
```

My question is: How do I document this function return type so that the Script Editor auto-completes for my function's return value as the [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet) object. Just like if the `openById` call were not wrapped in my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately completions won't work on a function's return value, whether it be in a library or the same script. I can see how this would be useful, and I suggest opening a feature request for it on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you Eric. Issue opened: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1380